# Bootstrap Typeahead without using javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

Even though there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125766/trouble-using-javascript-to-initialize-bootstrap-typeahead), I could not find a solution so here is the simplest code I could make

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
</head>  
<body>  
    <div class="well">  
        <input type="text" class="span3" id="search" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" />  
    </div>  

    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>  
    <script src="js/typeahead.js"></script>  
    <script>  
         var subjects = ['PHP', 'MySQL', 'SQL', 'PostgreSQL', 'HTML', 'CSS', 'HTML5', 'CSS3', 'JSON'];   
        $('#search').typeahead({source: subjects})  
    </script>  
</body>
```

and still not able to find what actually the problem is.

N.B :- jquery.js, typeahead.js are included, no console error(s)/ warning(s).
[image]

Comment: Works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/su7p8hs2/

Comment: @j08691 : Yes indeed, I am stunned. Are there any other minutes that I need to keep in mind ?

Comment: Can you reproduce it not working somewhere that we can see?

Comment: it works fine for me in all the online compilers, so I provided an image of the runtime and console itself

Comment: And you're sure JS in enabled and none of your browser's plugins are conflicting?

Comment: if JS was disabled then I could not have checked it successfully in the link you provied. Anyways my bad, will try the hard digging way :)